# How can I tell what dependencies a project has in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, flash-builder

I had a folder that contained a lot of projects, and imported them into Flash Builder/Eclipse.

I want one of these projects, and I'd like to remove the irrelevant projects from the workspace.

If I remove everything but the project I want, I get errors in the one I want, so it must have been dependent on something.

However, I have no idea what this project is dependent on. How do I find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, close all your projects (select all, right click and then close). Then, select the project you are interested in and open it. You will be asked if you want to also open the dependencies. This will allow you to see what's needed. You can then delete the projects that weren't opened.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Builder and Eclipse both give the option to close unrelated projects. Simply right click and select "Close Unrelated Projects". Delete those that were closed.